# What is the name of the sci-fi film or show in this YouTube Video?

Tags: story-identification

I just want to know the name of the film or show in this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH0hoViifJI) at 1:00 min.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [Extant: Season 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extant_(season_2)) as mentioned in the video description. Halle Berry is in the clip we see and in the show.

[image]

Comment: Oh, sorry I haven't seen it but thanks.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a link and a pic.

Comment: You didn't miss much.